# How to pass text from ListView item to a new Activity

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I am using `SimpleCursorAdapter` to fetch data from `SQLite` database to a `ListView`. Now I am trying to open an `Activity` which will contain the text from the `ListView`. I have written the code, but wherever I click, it is showing only the first item's text. Code is given below:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvListItem);

        String text = textView.getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("com.example.practise.write", text );
        startActivity(intent);

    }

});
```

Code in `SingleACtivity` class :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single);

    textTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWrite);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String write = intent.getStringExtra("com.example.practise.write");

    textTextView.setText(write);
}
```

Comment: how many textfields are there inside the listview,can you show your screen shot of the listview and what you want to pass to nextactivity?

Comment: How about changing to `textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvListItem);`?

Comment: The textView is dynamic, I mean items are added from database @Daryl

Comment: That works!!! Thanks! @Abbas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the textview of selected item then you will get the correct value If list item is just the `TextView` you can cast it to `TextView` like this

```
TextVie view = (TextView) view;
```

or if your textview is a sub view of your list item view then do this.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvListItem);
```